# object to json in spring

Tags: json, spring-boot, keyvaluepair

Below is the code snippet from different project files

**ProjectRepository.java**

```
@Query(value=" SELECT  p.id as project_id,p.project_status, t.id as test_suite_id, t.test_suite_status, ts.id as test_script_id,ts.test_script_status, tss.id as test_step_id, tss.test_step_status FROM project p LEFT OUTER JOIN test_suite t ON (p.id = t.project_id AND t.test_suite_status = 1) LEFT OUTER JOIN test_script ts ON (t.id = ts.test_suite_id AND ts.test_script_status=1) LEFT OUTER JOIN test_step tss ON (ts.id = tss.test_script_id AND tss.test_step_status=1) where p.team_id=:teamId and p.project_status=1 ",nativeQuery=true)
    public List<Object> getActiveProjectsWithTeamId(@Param("teamId") Long teamId);
```

**projectService.java**

```
List<Object> findActiveProjectsByTeamId(Long id) throws DAOException;
```

**projectServiceImpl.java**

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
 public List<Object> findActiveProjectsByTeamId(Long id) throws DAOException {

    log.info("entered into ProjectServiceImpl:findOneByTeamId");
    if (id != null) {
        try {
            // returns all projects of the specified team whose
            // project_status is active
            List<Object> project=projectRepository.getActiveProjectsWithTeamId(id);
            return project; 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception raised while retrieving the project of the mentioned ID from database : "
                    + e.getMessage());
            throw new DAOException("Exception occured while retrieving the required project");
        } finally {
            log.info("exit from ProjectServiceImpl:findOneByTeamId");
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I am getting below Output-

```
[ [ 1, true, 1, true, null, null, null, null ], [ 1, true, 2, true, null, null, null, null ], [ 1, true, 3, true, null, null, null, null ], [ 1, true, 5, true, null, null, null, null ], [ 1, true, 6, true, null, null, null, null ] ]
```

but I want the result in key value pair

Comment: How are you calling your service? Are you using a `@RestController`? Why are you using Object instead of creating your own entity?

Comment: yes using @RestController I've project entity class but that is mapped with 4 other entity class.  List<Project> is not working its giving SQL error column id not found.